# Store html string to oracle blob

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have to store string contains html data into oracle blob field using php.So I am using

```
utl_raw.cast_to_raw('myString')
```

But I cant store when myString size exceeds 4000 Bytes.
How to solve this?

Comment: Can you show us some more of your code?

Comment: $myString='<table ><tbody><tr><td>Some text</td></tr></tbody></table>';
query="update table_file set result=utl_raw.cast_to_raw('$myString') where slno=1";

Comment: And the result field of table_file is a BLOB or a VARCHAR2 field?

Answer (score 2):

> I have to store string contains html data into oracle blob field using php

Consider using **CLOB** rather than **BLOB**. The **HTML** can be considered a **string literal**. A string literal is inherently a **VARCHAR2**. So you cannot have a string literal longer than `4000 characters`. You need to **append** them each up to `4000 bytes` in chunks into a single **CLOB** to store beyond 4000 bytes.

From [**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020),

> A character large object containing single-byte or multibyte
>   characters. Both fixed-width and variable-width character sets are
>   supported, both using the database character set. **Maximum size is (4
>   gigabytes - 1) * (database block size)**.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t_clob
  2    (col CLOB
  3    );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT
  2  INTO t_clob VALUES
  3    (
  4    TO_CLOB
  5    (RPAD('<table ><tbody><tr><td>Some text</td></tr></tbody></table>', 4000, '*'))
  6    ||RPAD('<table ><tbody><tr><td>Some text</td></tr></tbody></table>', 4000, '*')
  7    ||RPAD('<table ><tbody><tr><td>Some text</td></tr></tbody></table>', 4000, '*')
  8    );

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT LENGTH(col) FROM t_clob;

LENGTH(COL)
-----------
      12000
```

Starting with Oracle 12c, the maximum size of **VARCHAR2** is now **extended** to **32767 bytes**. By default the parameter **MAX_STRING_SIZE** is **STANDARD** which can hold up to 4000 bytes.

```
SQL> show parameter MAX_STRING_SIZE

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
max_string_size                      string      STANDARD
```

You could alter the parameter value to **EXTENDED** and increase the maximum value of VARCHAR2 to 32767 bytes.

There are mainly two important steps:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET max_string_size=extended;

@?/rdbms/admin/utl32k
```

Answer (score 0):

Blob are used useally for binary data ( image, documents ) if you are using TEXTS use instead [CLOB](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefclob.html).

> BLOBs are binary LOBs. CLOBs are character LOBs.

With CLOB you can store more then 4000 bytes

Comment: "*With CLOB you can store more then 4000 bytes*" Yes, but you cannot form a string more than 4000 bytes in SQL. You need to do it in chunks.